# how do I put a gnome-terminal icon on the desktop?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How do I put a gnome-terminal icon on the desktop?  I already have one on the upper "panel" (ie: the strip across the top) but I need multiple ones on the desktop (so that I can customize with the --working-directory option).

I know this is possible because I already have some on the desktop.

Edit: Apparently, copying an existing one works.  However, I don't recommend this because after you copy it you will likely right click it and edit some properties to get it to do what you want it to do.  Then if you use the console to view the ~/Desktop folder, you will see that your property edits do not get reflected in the name of the executable file that implements the gnome-terminal.  The file system name will be an automatically generated name that is something like "original name (copy).desktop".  It's a little ugly that the name doesn't match your properties.

Comment: How do I access the terminal icon in Fedora20, default GUI install. I haven't use any Linux distro until Fedroa20 but now the traditional yerminal icon is not found any place in the menu on the graphical desktop. Anyone can help, assume I'm a Linux newbie that doesn't know where the common icons such as Terminal is found. I used to use Unix and early Linux built before the GUI for fancy like more recent Linx distros. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click -> Create launcher

Name:     Terminal
Command : gnome-terminal

Comment: You can also drag it from the menu: Applications/Accessories/Terminal.

Comment: Yes, if you have it there.

Comment: I am running CentOS-7.9 and I don't have a create launcher but I _DO_ have Terminal under Applications/System Tools.  I was able to drag that to my desktop and now I have something I can click on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just drag it feom the upper panel on to the desktop.  From there you can edit the properties and add your working-directory.

Comment: No you can't drag it.  I'm on ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx and I *can* drag.

Comment: Yes you can, I've just tried it on 10.04LTS and Gnome 2.30.2

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 you cannot drag it from the "panel" strip at the top.  However, you can drag it from the menu: Applications/Accessories/Terminal.

Comment: You cannot drag it if it is locked. Right-click the terminal icon in the upper panel and uncheck `Lock To Panel`